# Failed redirect from naked domain on SSL

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, ssl, dns

I have recently installed SSL on my AWS hosted wordpress site and my named domain is no longer working.

https:// example.com, https:// www.example.com, www.example.com are all working as expected.

> example.com is not working. example.com throws a connection refused error.

The Setup:

- Wordpress hosting is on a single AWS EC2 installed off the bitnami AMI. EC2 sits behind a classic load balancer.
- SSL certificate is managed on AWS certificate manager and was issued to *.example.com, example.com and www.example.com
- DNS uses route 53: www.doamin.com and domain.com have A records that point to the same load balancer alias
- .htacces has been modified with RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R,L]

What do I do to get this working?

Comment: Are you sure that http://www.example.com is working... try in a different browser and `telnet www.example.com 80`. What is the exact error message that you see and where?

Comment: Your right, both the non secure are not working.C:\>telnet www.example.com 80
Connecting To www.example.com...Could not open connection to the host, on port 80: Connect failed.

Comment: My rewrite rule is:<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 443
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://your-domain/$1 [R,L]
</IfModule>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTTPS does work, so the issue is not DNS. You mention a load balancer. The `Connection Refused` error indicates that your request is not making it to the load balancer or being accepted by the load balancer.

Check your security groups for the load balancer and ensure `port 80 inbound` is allowed.

Check your load balancer has a `listener on port 80`.

If you have modified the NACL's (Network Access Control Lists) on the public subnets of the loadbalancer, then you will need to allow `80 inbound and everything outbound`. The default NACL rules already allow this.

As an aside, I note that you are terminating SSL on the load balancer (because you are using an ACM cert). Depending on your configuration, this may mean that you are forwarding requests to your web server unencrypted on port 80. If so then your re-write rules will not correctly detect the use of HTTPS. AWS [has some documentation](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/redirect-http-https-elb/) explaining this in more detail.

Comment: Your right. It was a listener issue. Adding HTTP port 80 to the load balancer listener fixed it.